# How to access the HTML elements using C# in Asp.net MVC?

Tags: c#, html, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am doing a application using Asp.net MVC and In the model, I need to check whether the view page i am going to display have a element of specific `id`.I tried to use `WebBrowser` class to traverse my view page but it is showing error message as below.

```
`ActiveX control '8856f961-340a-11d0-a96b-00c04fd705a2' cannot be instantiated because   the current thread is not in a single-threaded apartment.`
```

at the `WebBrowser` class.

So Any idea to solve this.

Comment: You have completely misunderstood what MVC is

Comment: You know if a view page has an element with a specific id because you wrote the view page yourself and put the element on it in the .cshtml or .aspx file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have full control over your output HTML when developing apps using ASP.NET MVC. Define views to declare how the HTML should look like.

**You cannot access HTML elements (DOM Tree) programmatically using C# with ASP.NET MVC**

Comment: **Thanks buddy** I just needed clarification whether is it possible or not? and now i got the answer thanks a lot..